# QGIS 2.18 Installation on a Mac OS Sierra. The plug-ins will not open, I cannot tick the boxes

Tags: qgis, installation

[image]

Screenshot showing plugins trusted but boxes to not tick.

If it is a Python problem, why would it be as I have installed the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

They are already installed, and also working. The thick is white with a light gray border. I have the same ticks:

[image]

Without those light ticks, the plugin is deactivated.

And this image show you that plugins are activated (most part of those buttons aren't default tools):

[image]